# Realm Swift Multi User Login

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using Realm Swift in one of my iOS projects and one of the app requirements is to allow data of multiple users to co-exist. I am having an issue when the same users logs in as Realm is not able to identify the realm db file which is associated with that user.

Eg: So every time UserA re-logs in after logging out, a new Realm file is getting generated for UserA. This does not happen when UserA logs out and UserB logs in, then UserB logs out and UserA logs in.

UserA (logout) -> UserB (login) -> UseB (logout) -> UserA (login) [This works]

UserA (login) -> UserA (logout) -> UserA (login) [This does not work, a new Realm file is created and if there is a migration existing then try! Realm() also fails]

My AppDelegate code within application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions looks like the following.

```
func setDefaultRealmForUser() {

    var config = Realm.Configuration()

    // Inside your application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
    let currentLoggedInRegId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(Constants.UserDefaults.CurrentLoggedInRegId)

    if currentLoggedInRegId != nil {
        let registrationId = currentLoggedInRegId as! String

        // Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the username
        config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent?
            .URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(registrationId).realm")
    }

    // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
}
```

and my loginViewController code on success looks like the following

```
func setDefaultRealmForUser(onComplete: ()->()) {

    var config = Realm.Configuration()

    let currentLoggedInRegId = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(Constants.UserDefaults.CurrentLoggedInRegId)

    if currentLoggedInRegId != nil {
        let registrationId = currentLoggedInRegId as! String

        // Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the username
        config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent?
            .URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(registrationId).realm")
    }

    // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    onComplete()
}
```

Update: I have made it work for the time being by loading the default Realm before loading the user realm config, which looks like the below code:

```
func reloadRealmWithDefault(onComplete: ()->()) -> (Void) {
    var config = Realm.Configuration()

    let defaultRealm = "default"

    // Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the username
    config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.URLByDeletingLastPathComponent?
            .URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(defaultRealm).realm")

    // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

    onComplete()
}
```

But i am not completely happy with this approach as it's more a hack job.

What's the best way of doing a multi user login scenario?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not the greatest to continually change which Realm file the default configuration is pointing to. Realm itself caches references to files internally for performance reasons, so its not recommended to change the configuration once the file has actually been opened.

For a multiple user managed system, it would definitely make sense to have one Realm file per user.

On the code architecture level, I think it would be appropriate to have a singleton object that manages the state of the current user, and provides appropriately formatted `Configuration` objects whenever you need them.

```
class User {
    static let currentUser = User()
    private var userID: String? = nil

    public var configuration: Realm.Configuration {
        let configuration = Realm.Configuration()
        configuration.fileURL = URL(filePath: "\(userID).realm")
        return configuration
    }

    public func logIn(withUserID userID: String) {
        self.userID = userID
    }

    public func logOut() {
       self.userID = nil
    }
}

let userRealm = try! Realm(configuration: User.currentUser.configuration)
```